# como crear una excepción personalizada en Java

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee

Quería implementar una clase la cual lance una excepción llamada ExceptionZero que se encuenta implementada en otro módulo. La excepción se lanzará en caso de que, como argumento para el denominador, se pase un cero, se lanzará la excepción ExceptionZero

```
public class Rational throws new ExceptionZero {

    protected int num1, num2;

    public Rational(int num1, int num2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2; 

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las clases **NO** lanzan excepciones, sino los métodos de estas. La sintaxis que muestras es inválida en Java.

Si lo que quieres es que tú método lance dicha excepción debes hacer algo así:

```
public class Rational {

    protected int num1, num2;

    public Rational(int num1, int num2) {
        // Asumo que num2 es el denominador
        if (num2 == 0) {
            throw new ExceptionZero();
        }

        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2; 

    }
}
```

Por otro lado, si la clase `ExceptionZero` es un subtipo de `Exception`, también estás obligado a indicar en la firma del método que este puede lanzar dicha excepción (que se asemeja en algo a lo que intentaste)

```
    public Rational(int num1, int num2) throws ExceptionZero {
        // Asumo que num2 es el denominador
        if (num2 == 0) {
            throw new ExceptionZero();
        }

        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2; 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay unos problemas en tu clase:

```
public class Rational throws new ExceptionZero {

    protected int num1, num2;

    public Rational(int num1, int num2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2; 
    }
}
```

1. No es la clase que lanza la excepción, sino una función
2. En la firma de la función solo se dice `throws Exception` para decir que esa función podría lanzar una `Exception`, sin el comando `new` que sirve para crear una instancia de la excepción

Tu codigo tendría que parecer a esto:

```
public class Rational { //aquí no va nada

    protected int num1; 
    protected int num2;

    public Rational(int num1, int num2) throws ExceptionZero { //aquí dices al compiler que este constructór podría acabar lanzando una excepción
        if (num2 == 0) { //si el denominador es cero
            throw new ExceptionZero(); //entonces si lanzas la excepción
        }
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2; 
    }
}
```